# convert object column into date type column using python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, null

i have a csv file. that have a column named DOB. but when i want to change the data type into date type.  its gave error. 
here is the code

`b['DOB'] =  pd.to_datetime(b['DOB'], format='%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: What do the first few rows of `b['DOB']` look like?

Comment: "its gave error" is not a useful description of the problem.  Please read up on how to ask a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please append how you read in `b` and what error message you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read csv in pandas, read it like below: `pd.read_csv(file_name,parse_dates=True)`

parse_dates=True converts data to date format if it has date.